# What is the derivative of $y=x^y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $y=x^y$ ?

I have tried the below. Please correct me if I am wrong on any of the below.

$$y=x^y.$$

Taking natural log on both sides,

$$\log y = y \log x.$$

Differentiating on both sides,

$$\left(\frac1y - \log x\right)  y' = \frac{y}x$$

$$y' = \frac{y}{(\frac{x}y) - x\log x}$$

$$y' = \frac{y^2}{x(1-y\log x)}$$

Finally,

$$y' = \frac{x^{2y}}{x(1-x^y\log x )}$$

$$y' = \frac{x^{2y-1}}{1-x^y \log x}.$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The derivative of what with respect to what?

Comment: derivative of y with respect to x. ie., dy/dx. Is there any mistake in my calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=e^{y\ln (x)} $$

$$\ln (y)=y\ln (x) $$

$$x=e^{\frac {\ln (y)}{y}} $$

differentiating wrt $x $, we find

$$1=x \frac {1-\ln (y)}{y^2}y'$$

thus

$$y'=\frac {y^2}{x (1-\ln (y))} $$

Comment: I think you missed a "y" in the denomiator? The denominator should be x(1-y lnx) isn't it?

Comment: @AjeezMohd yes, i wrote that $\ln (y)=y\ln (x) $.

Comment: Thanks Fatima, your's also correct! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=(x^y)'=\left(e^{y\ln{x}}\right)'=x^y\left(y'\ln{x}+\frac{y}{x}\right),$$
which gives $$y'=\frac{yx^{y-1}}{1-x^y\ln{x}}$$

Comment: Which means what I have done is correct! Both are same. Thank you!!

Comment: @Ajeez Mohd You are welcome!

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Because $y=x^y$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Both are correct. I you want i delete mine.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima No! I don't want this. Your answer was accepted.